# Correct way to pass the char pointer to helper fuction and assign the value in C

Tags: c, pointers, char, dereference

I have some questions regarding assign the value to a char* in a helper function. If I have following code

```
int main() {
    char *p = malloc(6* sizeof(char));
    changeValue(p);
    printf("value of p=%s\n", p);

    return 0;
}
```

If I define following function, then it doesn't work:

```
void changeValue(char* input){
    input = "hello";
}
```

My first quesiton is what is the reason we can't assign a value directly to a pointer?
My previous understanding is because the space "hello" is created only during the changeValue scope and once it is out of the changeValue function, It is destroyed. However if I use the pointer of pointer to assign the value it works. Seems like "hello" space is not destroyed:

```
void changeValue(char ** input){
    *input = "hello";
}
```

In the main I need to change to:

```
char **p2 = malloc(sizeof(char*));
changeValue(p2);
printf("value of p2=%s\n", *p2);
```

And it works properly. My second question is what happened to the second function to make it work properly and which part is wrong in my previous logic?

I also find the following way to assign the value:

The changeValue function keep the same:

```
void changeValue(char ** input){
    *input = "hello";
}
```

In the main cpp I did following:

```
char *p = malloc(6* sizeof(char));
changeValue(&p);
printf("value of p=%s\n", p);
```

Seems like it also works properly but it doesn't make any sense to me. My third question is the input is the address of the p in memory, how dereference the address and assign a value to it works?

And what is the correct approach to assign a char* value in the helper function?

Thanks

Comment: `"hello"` is a string literal, its lifetime is the entire duration of the program

Comment: Also all your examples leak the memory allocated by `malloc`

Comment: "_My first quesiton is what is the reason we can't assign a value directly to a pointer?_" You can. You were just assigning to a _copy_ of the pointer created in the function argument list, because C always passes by value/copy. So the change is not seen outside. To change the value seen outside the function, you must pass a pointer to it, in this case a pointer-to-pointer. Then, you can dereference that pointer to get a modifable lvalue of what it points to. Sorry, but tthis is basic pointer usage and should be explained in any half-decent introduction to the concept of pointers.

Comment: You could have done the first version as `void changeValue(char *input) { strcpy(input, "hello"); }`. That changes the block of 6 bytes pointed to by `input` (and by `p` in `main()`), rather than changing the pointer itself.

Comment: @UnholySheep Sorry, please ignore the memory leak, you are right...

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes, strcpy do works properly but I feel it need extra work to do the copy. And the other disadvantage is I have to malloc the exact how much memory I need to the pointers, If I just use pointer of pointer I don't need to assign the exact memory

Comment: It depends what you want to do. Sure, you can copy pointers to string literals around. Just make sure you never modify the contents of the string literal through the pointer, because that would result in undefined behavior.

Comment: The third bit of code (`char *p = malloc(6* sizeof(char));` `changeValue(&p);`) is wrong because the memory pointed to by `p` might not be large enough to hold a pointer. On systems with 64-bit pointers, `sizeof(char *)` is typically 8, which is greater than the `6 * sizeof(char)` you allocated. By the way, `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, so `malloc(6 * sizeof(char))` is the same as `malloc(6)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first version, 'p' points to malloc'ed memory (6 bytes).  In the 2nd version, p2 points to memory that will contain an address.

In the 1st version of your helper function:

```
void changeValue(char* input){
    input = "hello";
}
```

Outside of that function, 'p' is still pointing to the malloc'ed memory.  When the program enters the changeValue() function, the value of 'p' is pushed onto the stack, where it is now referenced by a new field called 'input'... that only exists on the stack.  So by assigning it the literal "hello", you have replaced 'p' with the address of the string literal "hello".

Meanwhile, the location of 'p' is NOT the same as 'input'.  Once the function returns, the memory temporarily assigned to 'input' has been popped and is no longer relevant.

Maybe a diagram can help:

At first:

```
char *p = malloc(6* sizeof(char));


 (Stack)                 (Heap)

+-------+          +------------------+
|   p   +--------> | 6 * sizeof(char) |
+-------+          +------------------+
```

Next, the call to:

```
changeValue(p); // first version
```

affects the following:

```
 (Stack)                 (Heap)
+-------+
| input +----+
+-------+    |     +------------------+
|   p   +----+---> | 6 * sizeof(char) |
+-------+          +------------------+
```

and then:

```
input = "hello";

 (Stack)              (Heap)               (DataSegment)

+-------+                                    +-------+
| input +----------------------------------->|"hello"|
+-------+       +------------------+         +-------+
|   p   +-----> | 6 * sizeof(char) |
+-------+       +------------------+
```

and upon exit from 'changeValue', the stack is unwound and 'input' is no longer relevant.

```
 (Stack)                 (Heap)

+-------+          +------------------+
|   p   +--------> | 6 * sizeof(char) |
+-------+          +------------------+
```

and in the end of the main function, you now have a memory leak (the malloc'ed memory has not been freed).

One correct way to use the helper function is:

```
int main() {
    char *p = malloc(6* sizeof(char));

    changeValue(p, 6* sizeof(char) );   

    printf("value of p=%s\n", p);

    free( p ) ;        // <<<<<< avoid memory leak

    return 0;
}

void changeValue(char * input, size_t maxSize){
    // ... Copy "hello" into the space pointed to by input, taking
    //     care not to overrun the memory
    strncpy( input, "hello", maxSize ) ;
}
```

Comment: One of the diagrams makes it look like `input` is pointing to `p`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you also exaplain changeValue(&p)? I am little confused why &p can be treated as **char as input and works properly? Sorry for asking the silly question

Comment: changeValue(&p) was an error on my part.  I changed it in the answer.  Originally, you would pass '&p' only if you wanted to change where 'p' pointed to.  However in your example, you simply want to modify the content of the memory pointed to by 'p', and not 'p' itself.

Answer (score 1):

As to this question, I think the memory that stores the pointer s, whose size is dependent on the system, with the memory that the pointer s points to, which is 6 bytes big allocated, are two different concepts.

“The third bit of code (char *p = malloc(6* sizeof(char)); changeValue(&p);) is wrong because the memory pointed to by p might not be large enough to hold a pointer. On systems with 64-bit pointers, sizeof(char *) is typically 8, which is greater than the 6 * sizeof(char) you allocated. By the way, sizeof(char) is 1 by definition, so malloc(6 * sizeof(char)) is the same as malloc(6). ”